# Generics and anonymous classes (bug or feature?)

Tags: java, generics

This code not compiles, because of 'A' expression. It's interesting thing: in A expression expected

```
List<Foo>
```

generic type, but got

```
List<anonymous Foo>
```

(according compiler). Is it a jdk bug or feature?

```
 
interface Foo{ void doFoo(); }

public class GenericsTest {

    public static<V> List<V> bar(V v){ return new ArrayList<V>();}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> f = bar(new Foo(){ //A
            public void doFoo() { }
        }); //don't compiles

        Foo fooImpl = new Foo(){
            public void doFoo() { }
        };

        List<Foo> f2 = bar(fooImpl); //compiles
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A third option, because I like the syntax and I think it's underused (and probably not that well known), is to explicitly specific the generic parameter on the method call, as follows:

```
    List<? extends Foo> f = <Foo>bar(new Foo(){
        public void doFoo() { }
    });
```

It looks better (IMHO) when you have an explicit object that the method's being called on, e.g. `this.<Foo>bar(...)`.

Comment: Wow, now to have Eclipse to auto generate or at least suggest this option. I just inlined an inner class and the result was eroneous. No cast, I like it. Used it for Guava `Optional<T>`, also for `Optional.<Foo>absent()`.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's correct. Look at the type of the expression you're passing into `bar` in each case. The first time, you're passing in an anonymous type - so the return type is `List<anonymous type>`. The second time, you're passing in `Foo` (so `Foo` is the type argument), so the return type is `List<Foo>`.

You could make the first form work if you changed it to:

```
List<? extends Foo> f = bar(new Foo(){
            public void doFoo() { }
        });
```

or

```
List<Foo> f = bar((Foo) new Foo(){
            public void doFoo() { }
        });
```

To leave anonymous types out of it, it's the same difference as:

```
List<Object> objects = bar("hello"); // Won't compile
```

vs

```
Object x = "hello";
List<Object> objects = bar(x); // Will compile
```

Or, as Andrzej showed, use an explicit type argument.

Comment: I would have +1'ed this if I did not find the answer from Andrzej. Maybe you can update the answer or point to the solution from Andrzej?

Comment: @owlstead: Have added a small comment to the bottom. Given that Andrzej's answer is now the top one, I don't think it's worth duplicating it or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't compile because:

```
new Foo() {
  public void doFoo() { }
}
```

creates an anonymous subclass. It's a different type. You need to explicitly specify the type in that case:

```
List<Foo> f = bar((Foo)new Foo(){ //A
  public void doFoo() { }
}); //don't compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package theBestTrick;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface Foo{ void doFoo(); }

public class GenericsTest {

    public static<V> List<V> bar(V v){ return new ArrayList<V>();}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> f = bar(new Foo(){ //A
            public void doFoo() { }
        }); //don't compiles

        System.out.println(new Foo(){ //A
            public void doFoo() { }
        }.getClass());//class theBestTrick.GenericsTest$1 <- THAT'S WHY !!! 

        Foo fooImpl = new Foo(){
            public void doFoo() { }
        };

        List<Foo> f2 = bar(fooImpl); //compiles
    }
}
```

---

You have created **anonymous inner class**, but **anonymous classes** are **outer class subclasses** as you can see above.

IMHO it is not Bug or Feature, but something where you have know what is underhood ;)

---

```
    class FooImpl implements Foo{
        public void doFoo() { }
    }

    List<FooImpl> f3 = bar(new FooImpl()); //compiles
    List<FooImpl> f4 = bar(new FooImpl(){{
        System.out.println("I'm anonymous inner class");}}
    ); // not compiles
```

---

When you use "doubly brace" you get the same compilation errors.