# Java - anonymous instance of abstract class

Tags: java

**Type mismatch:** cannot convert from `BytecodeCodeProcessor<new AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor(){}>` to `BytecodeCodeProcessor<AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor>`

```java
public abstract class AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor {
}
```

```java
public class BytecodeCodeProcessor
     <T extends AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor> {

     public BytecodeCodeProcessor(ClassSourceResult classSourceResult, 
     T visitor) {

     }
}
```

```java
BytecodeCodeProcessor<AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor> processor = 
        new BytecodeCodeProcessor<>(classSourceResult, 
new AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor() {

});
```

Comment: You should review [The Java Tutorials. Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). You cannot create new instances on a generic definition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: i don't see where the error is. What does it mean "you cannot create new instances on a generic definition"?

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous class instantiated via `new AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor() {}` is a subclass of `AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor`. This anonymous subclass is *not* equal to the generic type parameter specified by `BytecodeCodeProcessor<AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor>`. *Anonymous* AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor != AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor, thus the compilation error. The code can be fixed in numerous ways, some of which are listed in the following link.

[Generics and anonymous classes (bug or feature?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642874/generics-and-anonymous-classes-bug-or-feature)

One solution:

```
BytecodeCodeProcessor<AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor> processor = 
    new BytecodeCodeProcessor<AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor>(
        classSourceResult, new AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor() {}
    );
```

Comment: It's not `BytecodeCodeProcessor` that is anonymous.

Comment: Nevertheless, filling in the diamond solves the compilation error.

Comment: For a different reason than the one you brought up. With the type argument, no type has to be inferred because you explicitly declare it. Without it, it's inferred to a type that makes the expression not assignable to `BytecodeCodeProcessor<AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor>`, in Java 7. Java 8's improved type inference has fixed this problem.

Comment: Java 8 gives a compilation error as well (on the diamond). Another SO topic, closer to the OP's problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642874/generics-and-anonymous-classes-bug-or-feature

Comment: I get no error in Java 8. I used OP's code as is. (Post it if you got it.) I would prefer if you edited your question to include the concepts discussed in the link you posted just now (or in the linked duplicate).

Comment: And also explain why what you suggest works.

Comment: Edited. The error I see in Netbeans is similar to the OP's: _incompatible types: Main.BytecodeCodeProcessor<<anonymous Main.AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor>> cannot be converted to Main.BytecodeCodeProcessor<Main.AbstractBytecodeCodeVisitor>_. I'm not running the very latest version of Java 8: build 1.8.0-b132.

Comment: You are or you aren't? It compiles fine for me with jdk1.8.0_20's `javac` which contains `java` build 1.8.0_20-b26. I would double check that Netbeans isn't using java 7.